# Java NoClassDefFoundError in Command Line

Tags: java, linux, command-line, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting the NoClassDefError when I try to run my program from the command line. It works fine in Netbeans, and javac compiles correctly.

I have a class called DistributedSystem which so far is only supposed to print "hello.".
The directory is src/distributedsystem/ which contains DistributedSystem.java, and DistributedSystem.class after the compile.

If I'm inside src/distributedsystem/ and run

```
java DistributedSystem
```

then I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DistributedSystem (wrong name: distributedsystem/DistributedSystem)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I also get the exact same error if I'm inside src/distributedsystem/ and run

```
java -cp . DistributedSystem
```

which is what I thought would fix the problem. I have also tried making sure classpath isn't set somewhere else, even though -cp should overwrite it. Anyone have any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code of DistributedSystem.java please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Again "wrong name" error when executing java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955017/again-wrong-name-error-when-executing-java-program)

Comment: you need to use `java distributedsystem.DistributedSystem` from the src folder assuming the class file is in `src/DistributedSystem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to folder src then compile from there and then run

Comment: Yeah this fixed the problem. Thought I had tried every combination, embarrassing! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The classpath should point to the base directory. It looks as if you are attempting to run class `DistributedSystem` in package `distributedsystem`, but your classpath is set to `project/bin/distributedsystem` instead of `project/bin`.