# JAVA applet Simplest program

Tags: java, applet, cmd, japplet, appletviewer

I'm trying to run a code on lifecycle of applet as shown. This file is saved as `Lifecycle.java`

I compiled it by

```
javac Lifecycle.java
```

then tried to run it by

```
appletviewer Lifecycle.java

package APPLETS;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class Lifecycle extends Applet
 {

    /*
    < APPLET
    code = "Lifecycle.class"
    height = "300"
    width = "300">
    < \APPLET>
    */

public void init() 
  {System.out.print("INIT");}

public void stop() 
  {System.out.print("STOP");}

public void start() 
  {System.out.print("Start");}

public void destroy() 
  {System.out.print("Destroy");}

}
```

APPLET is not loading then, though my code compiles successfully, no instructions are seen on command prompt. I'm just seeing a blank page with error -> `Start:applet not initialized`

HERE is the Lifecycle.html code-->

and here is the ERROR-

load: class APPLETS.Lifecycle.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: APPLETS.Lifecycle.class

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951695/receiving-wrong-name-noclassdeffounderror-when-executing-a-java-program-from-t/12044735#12044735

Answer (score 1):

The `appletviewer` is expecting to find HTML content so cannot parse the input file. Use `appletviewer` against a `URL` rather than a Java source file.

`appletviewer` is used to view applets using a `URL`. This `URL` can be in the format of a local or remote HTML document. Create a HTML document including the tag specifying your class and run the `appletviewer` against it.

*life.html:*

```
<APPLET CODE="APPLETS.Lifecycle" width="300" height="300"></APPLET>
```

then use

```
appletviewer life.html
```

The simplest folder structure for this to run is

```
./
 |life.html
 |-APPLETS 
    Lifecycle.class
```

Related: [The Java Applet Viewer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html)

Aside: Consider using the more up-to-date Swing `JApplet`.

Comment: <APPLET="APPLETS.Lifecycle" width="300" height="300"><\APPLET>

here shudn't i add the extension .java ...??

ie <APPLET="APPLETS.Lifecycle.java" ...??

Comment: sorry to say bro .. but m still getting the same problem..!

Comment: No the extension is optional and it is the `.class` file that you need. Is the error msg the same? Do you have the folder structure as above?

Comment: yess the structure is exactly the same as above..

and the error is till the same ..
here it is..

Comment: F:\JavaP\APPLETS>appletviewer Lifecycle.html
load: class APPLETS.Lifecycle.java not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: APPLETS.Lifecycle.java
        at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(AppletClassLoader.java:211)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(AppletClassLoader.java:144)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(AppletClassLoader.java:662)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:785)

Comment: Why do you have class `APPLETS.Lifecycle.java`? That should be `APPLETS.Lifecycle.class` or simply `APPLETS.Lifecycle` in the applet tag

Comment: ohh ya sorry ... it is APPLETS.Lifecycle.class i was wrote it wrong here.. it is correct in the actual code..

Comment: the code runs succesfully when i tried it in Java ide netbeans..
why its not running in cmdprompt..using appletviewer comand ..hv any idea?

Comment: 2 issues 1.) CODE attribute missing from tag 2) backslash in closing tag should be forward slash. As updated

Comment: Issues solved.. But the problem still persists..M sorry ..i know m troubling u .. :)

Comment: another thing ..i made 5 more programs on applet .. which successfully through cmd appletviewer command .. only this program has problem .. though it is the simplest of all possible applet programs.. :/

Comment: Can you attach the error and your life.html content to the question? Ensure that the class `Lifecycle.class` is in the _APPLETS_ folder.

Comment: The class file is not where its expected to be. 1) Are you running appletviewer from the same directory as life.html? Is `Lifecycle.class ` in the `APPLETS` directory relative to that dir? I tested this on my machine & works fine so I reckon its something very small...

Comment: yeahh .. m running appletviewer from the same directory as Lifecycle.html ...Lifecycle.class also is present in APPLETS package along wid Lifecycle.html and Lifecycle.java..
n yess may be you r right .. its sumthng very small ..and annoying too :/

Comment: do we have the set the path of appletviewer or sumthng like that ..bcoz i think that theres some problem with the path which is to be specified sumwhere..

Comment: No it should find the class from the class tag in the html file

Answer (score 0):

Put `Lifecycle.java` in a folder called `APPLETS`, and try running:

```
appletviewer APPLETS.Lifecycle
```