# Java Throws exception in thread main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling

I am a beginner in Java but not in OOP I have some experience in C and C++ and  PHP5 
For short I have "hello world" program for test

```
     package com.tutorial.helloworld;
     public class helloWorld {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
              System.out.print("hello world!!!\n");
      }

}
```

When I compile in console with javac compile with no error but when I run Java helloWorld
says

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: helloWorld (wrong name:  
 com/tutorial/helloworld/helloWorld)  and much more code
```

In eclipse run ok. If I delete package statement and compile manually  will run ok. but if I keep package statement throws that error. 
should I put the class file in a subdirectory com/tutorial/helloworld and is that ok how should I run from terminal and from what directory?

I am on mac os x and I am use to type code in edit and compile and run from console 
than run in a ice. I cannot make eclipse to work for c++ (c++ ide)and because of that I try to stick on the console with all languages I know or I learn.

Comment: Can you show the exact command used to run it? You probably have something off with your classpath (or didn't include the package name of helloWorld).

Comment: Are you in `<project dir>/bin` when you run java?

Comment: Also, in Java the convention is that Class Names Are Capitalized (so HelloWorld, not helloWorld).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951695/receiving-wrong-name-noclassdeffounderror-when-executing-a-java-program-from-t/12044735#12044735

Comment: I run javac helloWorld.java for compiling and for exec java helloWorld .

Comment: i will keep in mind the notation. @Pietu1998 I am in class generated directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java the class name consists of package name + the class's "first name". Therefore write

```
java com.tutorial.helloworld.helloWorld
```

You must also know where your `.class` files are. You must be in the directory containing the `com` directory for this to work, where the `.class` file finds itself inside `com/tutorial/helloworld` directory.

Comment: Or add location of directory containing `com/tutorial/helloworld/helloWorld.class` to classpath.

Comment: i understand thanks guys so need the dir structure of the package and run with above command