# Not Able to Compile Java Code via Command-line

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors, noclassdeffounderror

I wrote some Java code that takes several arguments using Eclipse. I was able to compile and execute the code just fine by entering the arguments in the "Run configurations."

However, I need to be able to run my code via command-line. This is what I tried:

```
javac -g ./MyCode.java
java MyCode ./fileOne.txt ./fileTwo.txt ./fileThree.txt
```

And the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mypackage/MyCode
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.MyCode
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I don't understand what is going on. My code does not have any bugs when I run through Eclipse. Help?

Comment: "...code that takes several arguments using Eclipse." Are these arguments part of `...void main (String[] args)`? If so, those are runtime arguments, not compile-time.

Comment: Check this out, probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951695/receiving-wrong-name-noclassdeffounderror-when-executing-a-java-program-from-t/12044735#12044735

Comment: Eclipse is doing this for you, just include the package name when you run the java command, as in "java mypackage.MyCode".  Execute that from the parent folder of the mypackage folder.

Comment: It was the package name. Thanks, Mark. If I could, I would choose your answer as the best.

Comment: @user3025403 np, if you like it that much, vote up the answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting up the classpath properly.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html