# java: NoClassDeFoundError?

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I'm starting to learn Java applet development (going to create a very, very simple game). I'm following a tutorial which doesn't use Eclipse per say, which I am using. I have a package set up called gameManager, inside I have a class to control elements of the window.

```
package gameManager;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class windowManager extends Applet {

public void init() { }

public void start() { }

public void stop() { }

public void destroy() { }

public void paint (Graphics g){ }

}
```

when I call the applet code into a HTML using

```
<applet code ="windowManager.class" width=700 height=400> 
</applet>
```

I get a NoClassDeFoundError with the message: windowManager (wrong name: gameManager /windowManager)

I'm a bit puzzled by this to be honest.

PS: Do note that I have the windowManager class set up like a template.

Comment: It's been a long time since I did an applet, but a class name should be fully qualifies (include packages before). In your case, `gameManager.windowManager`. Remember that the name of classes should begin with uppercase (not the reason of the error, but followin Java naming conventions is very useful).

Comment: Hi, 

When I change the HTML file to include hierarchy I get a ''ClassNotFoundException'' :/

EDIT: By including gameManager.windowManager in the HTML file, and then moving the HTML file to the gameManager directory I was able to load the applet. :)

Comment: maybe try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951695/receiving-wrong-name-noclassdeffounderror-when-executing-a-java-program-from-t/12044735#12044735

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the path to the class like this one:

```
<object codetype="application/java-archive"
     classid="java:MyApplet.class" width="400" height="300">
</object>
```