# Unable to execute java class from command line

Tags: java

I compiled a java project and generated `.class` files. If I try to run my code like below (refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12044735/147530):

```
java com.mycompany.mysubdomain.App
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

understandable as I haven't specified the classpath where `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` can be found. So I ran:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath
```

to get classpaths of my dependencies. Then I have tried running like so:

```
java -classpath /Users/me/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/vividsolutions/jts/1.13/jts-1.13.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar com.mycompany.mysubdomain.App
```

but now I get this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.mysubdomain.App
```

I don't understand why its complaining now. Note the crucial thing - when I omitted the classpath it was able to find `App`. The `ClassNotFoundException` happened because it couldn't find a dependency. But now why is it complaining that it can't find the `App` to begin with? How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't you think you should also provide the current directory (there your class is located) as part of the classpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding the directory where your own package tree resides to the classpath:

```
java -cp .:/Users/me/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/vividsolutions/jts/1.13/jts-1.13.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar com.mycompany.mysubdomain.App
```