# Problems Importing the Class Method that I Want to Use in Java

Tags: java, import, package

I am in the process of learning Java, and I have encountered a problem with importing another class's method. Whenever I try to compile the main program, I get this error: "error: package utils does not exist". Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the main program:

```
  // Summation of Primes


import mypackage.utils;
import java.util.*;

public class euler10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count = 0;

    ArrayList<Integer> primes = findPrimes(2000000);
    for (int prime : primes) {
        count += prime;
    }

    System.out.println(count);
}
}
```

And here is my class with the method I want to use. located in mypackage, which is in the same directory as the main program.

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.*;

public class utils {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> findPrimes(int n) {
        boolean[] isComposite = new boolean[n+1];

        for (int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++) {
            if (!isComposite [i]) {
                for (int j = i; i*j <= n; j++) {
                    isComposite [i*j] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int arrLength = isComposite.length;
        for(int index = 2; index < arrLength; index++) {
            if (!isComposite[index]) {
                primeList.add(new Integer(index));
            }
        }
        return primeList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Come on. Naming conventions! Class names being with UPPER CASE letters.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have imported your class, you should use an instance of that class to access their non static methods or to make it static and access it through the Class.method , or you can make the import to be static like following...

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

and then use just the functions

```
double r = cos(PI * theta);
```

[refference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first thing first you have to change your classes names to start with an uppercase characters please see [Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#15411):

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of
>   each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple
>   and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations
>   (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form,
>   such as URL or HTML).

Then add your package to euler10:

```
package mypackage;
```

And to access `findPrimes()` you must use `utils.findPrimes`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Euler10.java & Utils.java are in mypackage
2. Euler10.java, does not have an explicit import for utils because they are in same package
3. All class names begin with upper case
4. The findPrimes method is accesses using Utils, as its a static method

Euler10.java:

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.*;

public class Euler10 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count = 0;

    List<Integer> primes = Utils.findPrimes(2000000);
    for (int prime : primes) {
        count += prime;
    }

    System.out.println(count);
}
```

}

Utils.java:

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.*;

public class Utils {

public static ArrayList<Integer> findPrimes(int n) {
    boolean[] isComposite = new boolean[n+1];

    for (int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++) {
        if (!isComposite [i]) {
            for (int j = i; i*j <= n; j++) {
                isComposite [i*j] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int arrLength = isComposite.length;
    for(int index = 2; index < arrLength; index++) {
        if (!isComposite[index]) {
            primeList.add(new Integer(index));
        }
    }
    return primeList;
  }
}
```

Finally, my package layout:
[image]

Note: I didn't check the accuracy of the findPrimes function.

Compile and Run:

1. Navigate to mypackage directory and compile all java files i.e.

   `[mypackage]$ javac *.java`
2. Move a level up & run Euler10

   `[mypackage]$ cd ..`

   `[src]$ java mypackage/Euler10`

FYI, I got the output of: 1179908154

Note: Why did I move a level up before I ran java Euler10, this will explain: [Receiving "wrong name" NoClassDefFoundError when executing a Java program from the command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951695/receiving-wrong-name-noclassdeffounderror-when-executing-a-java-program-from-t)

Comment: I fixed all of the small things like naming conventions, etc. I put both files in the same folder (mypackage) tried to compile euler10 again, and an error of "cannot find symbol" for the variable Utils arose.

Comment: @Broke.College.Kid23, I believe you are trying to compile and run via command line. I have edited my post with compile and run instructions. Hope that helps, thanks.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to delete all of the path environment variables, reinstall Java, and now it works well. Thanks for the help though!